# Can import all THREE.js post processing modules as ES6 modules except OutputPass

Tags: javascript, import, three.js, importerror, es6-modules

I am trying to [replicate this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_postprocessing_sao.html) but with modules imported from CDN.

With the following import map:

```
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.8.0/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0",
            "three/addons/": "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/"
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the following imports

```
// ...
import { EffectComposer } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/EffectComposer';
import { RenderPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/RenderPass';
import { SAOPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/SAOPass';
import { OutputPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/OutputPass';
```

I get an error only for the last import "OutputPass":

```
GET https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/three@v0.136.0-4Px7Kx1INqCFBN0tXUQc/dist=es2019,mode=raw/examples/jsm/postprocessing/OutputPass net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I have tried figuring out why this module won't import correctly, but I have not found a single clue.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OutputPass` was added with `r153`, you are importing `r136`. So you can easily fix the issue by just upgrading `three.js` to the latest version.